# 2.8.1 of SDK - Class ErpEndpoint missing

Tags: s4sdk

In your samples the class com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.connectivity.ErpEndpoint is used (see [Deep Dive 5 Blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/12/06/deep-dive-5-with-s4hana-cloud-sdk-executing-bapis-inside-s4hana-on-premise-from-your-cloud-application/)) however this class is missing in SDK 2.8.1.

How can a BapiQuery be created using SDK 2.8.1?

Answer (score 1):

In version 2.0.0 of the S/4HANA Cloud SDK, the `ErpEndpoint` was removed as per the [release notes](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/6c02295dfa8f47cf9c08a19f2e172901/1.0/en-US/index.html).
The guidance is to use `ErpConfigContext` instead.

Addition: The deep dive 5 was updated accordingly.

Comment: You can also find more details here: https://blogs.sap.com/2018/06/05/migration-guide-moving-to-version-2.0.0-of-the-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk/